# Annotate IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, annotations, ixmlserializable

I've created a type, which implements IXmlSerializable and uses XmlSchemaProviderAttribute to define its schema, for use in a WCF service. All according "best practice"/MSDN as far as I know.

Long story short, I must use IXmlSerializable for various reasons (can't use DataContract), and I want my type to be documented in the XSD schema by using xs:annotation and xs:documentation. It seems like everything BUT the type itself can be annotated, somehow the type annotation is stripped from the schema.

Can anyone explain why, what's wrong with my code, or a working solution?

Using the class below as parameter/return value to an operation, or as part of a DataContract, correctly adds the ComplexType to the schema, with everything except the type annotation.

Specifically, this line has no effect (though with a breakpoint at the return statement, I can verify the annotation is actually there, looking correct):

```cs
type.Annotation.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaDocumentation { Markup = TextToMarkup("Documentation for MyClass") });
```

**Full sample**:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="MyNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="MyNamespace">
 <xs:complexType name="MyClass">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="MyId" type="xs:integer">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>Annotation for id element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="MyStringChoice" type="xs:string">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Choice number 1</xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MyIntChoice" type="xs:integer">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Choice number 2</xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="MyClass" nillable="true" type="tns:MyClass"/>
</xs:schema>
```

```cs
[XmlSchemaProvider("GenerateSchema")]
public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public static XmlQualifiedName GenerateSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemas)
    {
        //Create choice
        var choice = new XmlSchemaChoice();
        var choice1 = new XmlSchemaElement
            {
                Name = "MyStringChoice",
                SchemaTypeName = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).QualifiedName,
                Annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation()
            };
        var choice2 = new XmlSchemaElement
            {
                Name = "MyIntChoice",
                SchemaTypeName = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.Integer).QualifiedName,
                Annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation()
            };
        choice1.Annotation.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaDocumentation { Markup = TextToMarkup("Choice number 1") });
        choice2.Annotation.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaDocumentation { Markup = TextToMarkup("Choice number 2") });

        choice.Items.Add(choice1);
        choice.Items.Add(choice2);

        //Create id element
        var id = new XmlSchemaElement
            {
                Name = "MyId",
                SchemaTypeName = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.Integer).QualifiedName,
                Annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation()
            };
        id.Annotation.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaDocumentation { Markup = TextToMarkup("Annotation for id element") });

        //Create sequence
        var sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();
        sequence.Items.Add(id);
        sequence.Items.Add(choice);

        //Create type
        var type = new XmlSchemaComplexType
        {
            Name = "MyClass",
            Particle = sequence,
            Annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation()
        };

        //ANNOTATE TYPE: THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!!
        type.Annotation.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaDocumentation { Markup = TextToMarkup("Documentation for MyClass") });

        //Add type to schema
        var schema = GetOrCreateSchema(schemas, "MyNamespace");
        schema.Items.Add(type);

        //Return XmlQualifiedName for non-anonymous types
        return new XmlQualifiedName("MyClass", "MyNamespace");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static XmlNode[] TextToMarkup(string text)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var t = doc.CreateTextNode(text);
        return new XmlNode[] {t};
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find schema matching the namespace, or create and add schema to set if it doesn't exist
    /// </summary>
    private static XmlSchema GetOrCreateSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemas, string targetNamespace)
    {
        var schema = schemas.Schemas(targetNamespace).OfType<XmlSchema>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (schema == null)
        {
            schema = new XmlSchema
            {
                TargetNamespace = targetNamespace,
                ElementFormDefault = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified
            };
            schemas.Add(schema);
        }
        return schema;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //Implementation ommited
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        //Implementation ommited
    }
}
```